# Use Same Email Address On Multiple User Accounts

Tags: emails, user-profile

I am needing to set up two distinct users (one for each of two LDAP log ins) and I need for them both to use the same admin email address.  However, Craft 2 will not let me do this.  Is there a way to do this for this type of special admin/ldap user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not natively because Craft places a unique index on the `email` column of the `craft_users` table in the database.

Without knowing the specifics of what you're trying to achieve, I'd probably write a custom plugin that listened to user registration events in Craft and saved the necessary LDAP information in its own database tables that had foreign keys back to the native `craft_users` table.

Comment: Even with the custom plugin, would I need 2 different email addresses?